# SearchBar calls a method for each letter

Tags: react-native, search

I have SearchBar from react-native-elements component working fine in filtering data, but it is not performative, once it's calling search method for each typed letter.

I mean, if I type TEST, it will display "T" results, then "TE" results, then "TES" results and finally "TEST" results, one at time.

I'm not intending to use submit button. The official docs only shows onChangeText to trigger some method.

**Question:**
So, is there a way to call the method only one time when typing is done?

**SearchBar Component:**

```
<SearchBar 
  onChangeText={(text) => this.search(text) }
  onClear={this.setState({noMatches: true})}
  showLoadingIcon={this.state.searching}
/>
```

**Search Method:**

```
 search = (text) => {

        requestMonitorados(text).then((value) => {

                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.setState(data: value); //Updating list of data
               }, 3000);

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delay calling `this.search` until no new key input is detected for some time:

```
onChangeText={(text) => {
  this.text = text;
  clearTimeout(this.timeout); // clears the old timer
  this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.search(this.text), WAIT_TIME);
}}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearTimeout(this.timeout);
}
```